# Notation in Geometry

Tags: geometry, notation

I have this problem to solve:

[image]

The translation is:

Been the next angles:  $\angle ABC$, $\angle DEF$ and $\angle GHI$,  if $\angle ABC$ is "Parallel?" to $\angle DEF$ and $\angle GHI$ is parallel (again?) to the other 2 angles, then compute the measure of $\angle DEF$ if m(GHI)=75 grades.

But, obviously there are errors in it.   What do not make sense to me is section marked in blue.  $\angle ABC$ "Parallel?" to $\angle DEF$ and almost immediately again something that makes me think in Parallel angles.

Do I miss something here? How can an angle be "parallel" to another? Are they flat angles? ($180^\circ$)

Comment: Skallab , can you please write the question (translated  form )yourself instead of pasting pictures. It's hard to read .

Comment: Making a simplification of the question is suppose it can be reduced to this:  what means two parallel angles?  In other words ABC//DEG express something like parallel angles.  Do this exist? or  I misunderstood the two parallel lines in-between the 2 angles

Answer (score 0):

I just receive this theorem:

**Theorem 2.3**

Been 3 rect lines R1, R2 and R3 in which R1 is parallel to R2 and R3 intersects R1 and R2.  And being *a* and *b* two alternate-external opposites angles. **Then *a=b***

**We can say that *a* and *b* are PARALLEL ANGLES**

[image]

Also I have this:

**Definition 2.3**
Been 2 angles *a* and *b* if their sides are perpendiculars "in pairs" we can say that both angles are perpendicular angles.  If their sides are parallel "in pairs" then we say that both angles are **parallels**

[image]

**Do anyone has any comment?**